# Why is there not a starter pom for spring-oauth2?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I would like to standardize my projects using the spring-boot, however it strange not find a starter pom to use the spring oauth.
Spring oauth was discontinued?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2

Comment: Confuses the setup documentation, for other dependencies it gives some examples.

Answer (score 1):

valid setup:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```